# Custom UIView resizing while rotating

Tags: ios

I know that there are several similar questions, but I still didn't find a proper solution.
I've just created a test project with a custom view:

```
@interface CustomView : UIView

//..

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    }
    return self;
}
```

and View Controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CustomView *cv = [(CustomView *) [CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview: cv];
}
```

In the Landscape Mode we can see:

[image]

How to fix it?
I know about `layoutSubviews`, but `1.` it's not called while rotating; `2.` How I can resize a view here?

Comment: ios 5 and ios6 very different while rotating

Comment: try uncheck autoresize subview it might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set autoresizingMask.

```
CustomView *cv = [(CustomView *) [CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
cv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
[self.view addSubview: cv];
```

You can also have a look at autolayout

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/UnderstandingAutolayout.html

Regards,